# Download and View PDF inside android application from Webservice

Tags: android, web-services, pdf, bufferedreader, filereader

I am trying to download and open a PDF file inside android application i.e. without using any other application(pdf viewer,etc) installed on phone.

Please tell me is it possible??

So far What I have done is :

PdfViewerActivity.java

```
public class PDFViewerActivity extends Activity {
    private Button mDownLoadPdf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pdfviewer_activity);
    }

    public void downloadPDF(View v)
    {
//        new DownloadFile().execute("http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf", "maven.pdf");
        new DownloadFile().execute("http://dev-hop-docs.seechangehealth.com/SitePages/PDFLoader.aspx?test=abc");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Download finished,Viewing PDF...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        view();
    }

    public void view()
    {
        File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testthreepdf/" + "privacy notice.pdf");  // -> filename = maven.pdf
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        try{
            startActivity(pdfIntent);
        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(PDFViewerActivity.this, "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String fileUrl = strings[0];   // -> http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf
//            String fileName = strings[1];  // -> maven.pdf
            String fileName = "privacy notice.pdf";
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "testthreepdf");
            folder.mkdir();

            File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);

            try{
                pdfFile.createNewFile();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileLoader.downloadFile(fileUrl, pdfFile);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my FileLoader.java

```
public class FileLoader {
    private static final int  MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory){
        try {

            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
//            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
//            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0 ){
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Using the above code , I am getting following error :

Invalid PDF Format.

But when i paste this webservice url on pc browser it opens a pdf.

Please tell me what I have done wrong. Or is there any other way to achieve it.

Comment: It' not possible. So better to open your PDF in WebView. Take a look [integrating-pdf-in-android-application](http://dixitpatel.com/integrating-pdf-in-android-application/)

Comment: are you sure this is not possible ?? @MD

Comment: @S I already work with this. I mean it's possible using some MuPDF lib but customized by your self...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to download and open a PDF file inside android application i.e. without using any other application(pdf viewer,etc) installed on phone.

Not according to the code in your question. You are specifically attempting to open the PDF file in "other application(pdf viewer,etc) installed on phone".

> Using the above code , I am getting following error : Invalid PDF Format.

The file does not exist yet. You need to wait to do your `view()` logic until `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`. Right now, you are trying to `view()` the file while the download is going on in a background thread.

I also would recommend that you call `flush()` and `getFD().sync()` on your `FileOutputStream` before you `close()` it, to ensure that all bytes are written to disk before you try launching the third-party PDF viewer.

Comment: Thanks for answering this..but i don't know how to open pdf without using any third party app installed on phone..please guide me on that..is it possible to view pdf file without using pdfviewer and webview??

Comment: @Shruti: As you are well aware, "questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow". Please feel free to use a search engine to search for `android pdf viewer library`.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goals you can use [MuPDF](http://mupdf.com/doc/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android) library for Android. But first of all you need to download PDF file. Also you can use [EBookDroid](https://code.google.com/p/ebookdroid/) library which supports PDF, DjVu, EPUB, RTF, etc.

Answer (score 0):

@shruti yes it is possible to read pdf in android application without third party application using pdfrenderer. i have used this google sample for my app 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic
i hope it will help .